# Is there a way to convert QnA Questions into LUIS Intent Utterances

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-language-understanding, azure-bot-service, azure-qna-maker

I followed this Microsoft Documentation to make my implementation of a Bot that uses LUIS to route users questions to QnAMaker: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-tutorial-dispatch?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=cs

Basically I noticed in the V3 Documentation(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/tutorials/integrate-qnamaker-luis) (As there is no mention of it in V4)
it says:

> Add an intent for each QnA Maker knowledge base. The example
>   utterances should correspond to questions in the QnA Maker knowledge
>   bases.

My question is, other than manually copying all the questions from QnA Maker to each individual Intent (Assuming I have multiple KBs) is there an easier way to do this? Eg export the file from QnA Maker or something similar?

Comment: How did you go with my answer below?

Comment: Hmmm not too well basically I was trying to add intents for my own knowledge base but for kept getting a bad argument when I was trying to do the dispatch create command.
But it worked for the sample they provided just not my own

Comment: Mind posting the exact error message you get when running the dispatch create command?

Comment: ERROR
One or more errors occurred. (The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.)

Request url: https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/qnamaker/v4.0/knowledgebases/9c1336aa-d35e-42b1-84ff-ef868ac4d4a2/Test/qna
Response: {
  "error": {
    "code": "BadArgument",
    "message": "Please verify azure search service is up, restart the WebApp and try again"
  }
}

Comment: But it's weird because the example request works fine but as soon as I add my own kb-id and kb-name and new intent name I get the error

Comment: Does testing your QnA Maker KB through the QnA Maker portal work or do you get errors there too? I would export your current KB, then create a new one, import the backup of your original one then try to link that new KB up via dispatch. Another thing you could try to verify your original KB is to download [this sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/samples-work-in-progress/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/11.qnamaker) and add your QnA Maker KB details to the appsettings.json file and see if it works, if it doesn't then the Azure Search associated with your KB is the problem.

Comment: Tried doing a new one like you said but to no avail, could you please have a quick look at this crude image and see if I'm constructing the command properly/getting the correct info from the correct location?: [Imgur](https://i.imgur.com/diJYe2u.jpg)

Comment: Hmm.. I can't seen anything obviously wrong with your dispatch command. How did you go with trying the qna sample I linked in my previous comment?

Comment: Yeah works okay when I plug it up to the template, that's alright just going to have to do it manually for now

Comment: If you wanted to automate this somewhat you could use the [Download knowledgebase](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5a93fcf85b4ccd136866eb37/operations/knowledgebases_download) API method to get all of the questions, then the [Example utterances](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c08) API method to add the questions against the correct intent (ignoring the entityLabels property).

Comment: This is a good idea, might implement it this way instead, appreciate all your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done using the [Dispatch](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-tools/tree/master/packages/Dispatch) tool. Essentially what it does is downloads the questions from your QnA Maker KBs and creates a new LUIS app with "dispatch" in the name. Inside this new app a intent will be added for each of your QnA Maker KBs, the naming will be `q_<kb_name_here>`, the questions from the relevant KB will be added to this intent as utterances.

How to do this is outline under the [Create the dispatch model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-tutorial-dispatch?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=cs#create-the-dispatch-model) section of the documentation that you linked.

You will need to have [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/) which comes with `npm` installed to do the following from the command line in your `CognitiveModels` folder (rough guide):

```
// install botdispatch package
npm i -g botdispatch

// initialise a dispatch file
dispatch init -n <filename-to-create> --luisAuthoringKey "<your-luis-authoring-key>" --luisAuthoringRegion <your-region>

// add references to luis and qna apps
dispatch add -t luis -i "<app-id-for-weather-app>" -n "<name-of-weather-app>" -v <app-version-number> -k "<your-luis-authoring-key>" --intentName l_Weather
dispatch add -t luis -i "<app-id-for-home-automation-app>" -n "<name-of-home-automation-app>" -v <app-version-number> -k "<your-luis-authoring-key>" --intentName l_HomeAutomation
dispatch add -t qna -i "<knowledge-base-id>" -n "<knowledge-base-name>" -k "<azure-qna-service-key1>" --intentName q_sample-qna

// generate a dispatch model
dispatch create
```

Then in the LUIS portal you will have to find your new app and Publish it before you will be able to use it. then follow the steps under the [Use the dispatch model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-tutorial-dispatch?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=cs#use-the-dispatch-model) to take advantage of LUIS for routing.